# Side menu does not extend

Tags: java, android, xml, sidebar, navigationview

I try to do the side menu that slides out from the left side.
I use a few guides, but my menu does not come out, but is immediately visible on the home screen.

The guides, when the side menu was at the center of the screen instead of the left side just added this line:

```
android:layout_gravity="start"
```

but in my application it does not work ...

My `activity_maps.xml`

```
  <LinearLayout

        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">





            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="3">

                <fragment
                    android:id="@+id/map"
                    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    tools:context="ru.marks.mygps1.MapsActivity"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_height="0dp">

                <Button
                    android:text="but1"
                    android:id="@+id/B1"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent" />


            </LinearLayout>



        <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"

            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
            android:layout_gravity="start" >


        </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>


        </LinearLayout>
```

My `navigation_menu.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <item android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:title="Button 1" />
    <item android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:title="Button 2" />
    <item android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:title="Button 3" />

</menu>
```

I can not fix it, help.

```
edit:
```

[before adding the side menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NRnr.png)

[after](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N8qIW.png)

I would like to make this menu was coming out of the left side

Code with my side:

```
  <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"

                app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu"
                android:layout_gravity="start" >


            </android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: I am unable to understand your problem statement ..
But i saw your xml .. correct it .. it have ambiguities. Like 
<LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal" 
                android:layout_width="match_parent" 
(width would be 0dp) when orientation is horizontal and height would be wrap or etc.

Comment: I added two screenshots

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- orientation = horizontal (width: 0dp , Height:choice , weight: any >1 )
- orientation = vertical (width: choice , Height:0dp , weight: any >1 )

**OR Try Android Default Drawer Layout**

Comment: still this same, I added two screenshots in 1st message

Comment: try to change the width of navigationView

Comment: I now see the sidebar and its application, but one thing is on the second, and the sidebar does not respond to touch, not hiding but just on the main screen

Comment: It is not working because you have not implement the Navigation Drawer fully..
It is recomended for you to implement android studio's default side Nav bar.... for this ... Righ click on Project hierarchy selec new > activity > select Navigation Drawer Activity

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will help .. change layout_width

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

to

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
```